# Lowest Common Multiple Program

Tags: c++

I tried making a program to find the lowest common multiple of any two numbers. I have gotten most of the way there but my program prints all of the common multiples from 1-1000000 instead of just the first one. How do I make it print only the first one
?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "Find the lowest common multiple of two numbers, just enter them one after the other" << endl;
    int firstNum;
    int secondNum;
    cin >> firstNum;
    cin >> secondNum;
    int i;

    for (i = 1; i < 1000001; i++) {

        if (i % firstNum == 0 && i % secondNum == 0) {

            cout << "these two number's LCM is" << i << endl;
        }
    }



    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Just add a `break` after `cout << "these two number's LCM is" << i << endl;`

Comment: [`break;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/break). Also, please reconsider your use of what are often considered bad practices: [`using namespace std;`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191) and [`endl`](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.co.uk/2016/02/why-you-shouldnt-use-stdendl.html) (those are links to explanations).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `break` to end a loop. In your case, you want to add it at the end of your `if` statement:

```
for (i = 1; i < 1000001; i++) {
    if (i % firstNum == 0 && i % secondNum == 0) {
        cout << "these two number's LCM is" << i << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is a `break` statement as others have mentioned.

But a better solution: [`lcm`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/lcm) is standardized in C++17! So you can just do:

```
cout << lcm(firstNum, secondNum) << endl;
```

If you don't have access to C++17 yet this is already available in the `namespace experimental`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/lcm

Answer (score 0):

After finding the first one you need to leave from for loop, that is why it keeps printing other values.

```
for (i = 1; i < 1000001; i++) {

if (i % firstNum == 0 && i % secondNum == 0) {
    cout << "these two number's LCM is" << i << endl;
    break;
}
```

}